# Solr highlighting words in synonyms.txt along with query terms

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr6

I am a newbie to Solr and trying to find out what is the general solution being used for the multi-word synonym issue with highlighting:

 1. When we search for a **hair brush**, the word **toothbrush** is also being **highlighted as toothbrush is in the synonyms.txt** file.

```
HAIR BRUSH,HAIRBRUSH,HAIR-BRUSH,HAIRBRUSHES,HAIR BRUSHES 
TOOTH BRUSH,TOOTHBRUSH,TOOTH-BRUSH,TOOTHBRUSHES,TOOTH BRUSHES
```

1. Could you please let me know if this is because the SynonymGraphFilterFactory is being used in both indexing-time and query-time?
2. If not, what needs to be done so that the terms not matching the query term is not highlighted.

The schema.xml configuration for the fieldType is as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
           <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" 
                    pattern="[({.,\[\]/})]" replacement=" "/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" preserveOriginal="1"  catenateAll="1"  />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
           <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" 
                    pattern="[({.,\[\]/})]" replacement=" "/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" /> 
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

We are using Solr: 6.5.1

Comment: This is only half of an answer: You're using the Whitespace Tokenizer for both the index and the query.  So when you query for "hair brush", that's tokenized into "hair" and "brush", and you search the index for both.  That doesn't tell you how to make it work correctly, though.  You'll have to change your tokenizers, but I don't know offhand how to both preserve compound words (i.e. actually having "tooth brush" and "tooth-brush" in the index, as well as "tooth" and "brush") while still splitting at word separators.  You need to tokenize all single and two word combinations I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I will change the tokenizers as per your feedback and see if there is anything that will preserve the compound words.